# Firebase database rules for particular user

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a db where I need read access to all users and 
write access when invoked in an apps script running by the user = 
'firebaseowner@gmail.com'

My firebase structure is

```
ABC/AAA1/date 
ABC/AAA2/date 
ABC/AAA3/date 
ABC/AAA4/date
```

The rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false,
    }
}
```

How do I make the rule to allow write when invoked by the user 'firebaseowner@gmail.com' in the apps script.

I use https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/reference for inserting data

Comment: Keep empty rules ( remove rules)

Comment: what is the default rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the [`auth` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables).

To define the security rules that allow write access to all the locations by this email address `firebaseowner@gmail.com` only:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email == 'firebaseowner@gmail.com'"
  }
}
```

To define the security rules that allow write access to only the location `/users` by this email address `firebaseowner@gmail.com` only:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "users": {
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email == 'firebaseowner@gmail.com'"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My firebase structure has no users/ -  is it necessary that allowing .read as true will make other users to read entire database?

Comment: you can secure your firebase database and allow read / write access to certain location, `/users` is the location and you can change `/users` anythings you want, such as `/threads`, `/ABC` etc..

Comment: `.read` / `.write` are internal keywords, this is helpful too https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#rule_types

Comment: I save AAA1, AAA2 as base 64 values of email. is it possible to implement in the rule like Utilities.base64encode($email)?

Comment: rules only have a limited set of methods provided, i don't think it has base64 encode / decode. you should make the raw data stored in somewhere if you want to include in security rules.

Comment: When I simulate this gives auth=null and won't allow the owner to use getData(). How will I make it auth !=null. I use the library (Romain) listed above.

Comment: how did you simulate?